# Сумма массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Решаю задачу на CodeWars, нужно вернуть сумму массива.**

> Напишите функцию, которая принимает массив чисел и возвращает сумму
> чисел. Числа могут быть отрицательными или нецелыми. Если массив не
> содержит чисел, вы должны вернуть 0.
>
> Примеры Вход: [1, 5.2, 4, 0, -1] Выход: 9.2
>
> Вход: []
> Выход: 0
>
> Вход: [-2.398] Выход: -2.398

**Я написал код таким образом, но получаю ошибку.**

```
function sum (numbers) {
  
  let sum = 0;
  let arr = [];
  
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.lenght; i++) {
   if (numbers[i] == arr) return 0;
   sum += numbers[i];
  }
  return sum;
 };
```

**Ошибка вот такая:**

> Test Results: Tests test expected 0 to equal 9.2 Completed in 3ms
> Completed in 6ms

**Где я допустил ошибку?) Спасибо**

Comment: Банальная опечатка lenght это не length.  И проверка внутри цикла бессмысленная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы не совсем поняли условие:

> Если массив не содержит чисел, вы должны вернуть 0.

Это означает, что если на вход поступит пустой массив `[]`, то функция должна сразу же вернуть **0**;

```js
function sum(numbers) {
  if (numbers.length == 0) return 0; // возвращаем 0, если длинна массива равна 0
  let sum = 0;
  for (let number of numbers) {
    sum += number;
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(sum([])); // 0
console.log(sum([1, 5.2, 4, 0, -1])); // 9.2
```

В этой строчке вы совершаете проверку совсем иного толка:

```
if (numbers[i] == arr) return 0;
```

Семанитика строчки такова:

> если текущий элемент массива `numbers` равен массиву `arr` возвращаем **0**;

Элемент массива `numbers[i]` никогда не будет равен массиву `arr`, только если вы сами не присвоите ему это значение вот так: `numbers[i] = arr`, т.к даже если `numbers[i]` будет пустым массивом, то вам выдаст `false`

```
console.log([] == []); // false
```

это 2 разных массива.

Так же, если массив будет состоять не из `number`, а из примитивов других типов, то можно сначала проверить, являются ли все элементы массива `number`:

```js
function sum(numbers) {
  if (numbers.length == 0) return 0; // возвращаем 0, если длинна массива равна 0
  let sum = 0;
  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (typeof number !== 'number') return 0; // не все элементы массива типа number
    sum += number;
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(sum([[], [], {} , 2, true, false]))
```

Или мы можем пропускать элементы другого типа и суммировать только `number`:

```js
function sum(numbers) {
  if (numbers.length == 0) return 0; // возвращаем 0, если длинна массива равна 0
  let sum = 0;
  for (let number of numbers) {
    if (typeof number !== 'number') continue; // переходим к следующей итерации
    sum += number;
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(sum([[], [], {} , 2, true, false, 5]))
```

Comment: `if` в вашем решении не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких преобразований идеально подходит метод [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const array = [1, 5.2, 4, 0, -1];

function getSumm(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
}

console.log(getSumm(array));
```

Comment: Подробностей не хватает, вы бы хоть ссылку оставили какую-нибудь.

Comment: @ΝNL993 а какие тут подробности, это нативная функция

Comment: @Jean-Claude к примеру краткое объяснение? (и не функция, а метод...)

Comment: @ΝNL993 метод внутри объекта и есть функция. Таких объяснений уже валом на сайте, достаточно поискать. Каждый год одно и то же, сотни одинаковых вопросов.